# Golang how to create map to pointer to slice using make

Tags: go, pointers, hashmap

I want to create a dynamically initialized bitmap data structure. I'm trying to use the golang maps for this:

```
type Register map[bool]*[]bool
```

The way I'm initializing the map is:

```
register := make(Register)
register[true] := make(*[]bool, len(arr))  // arr is the array for which i want to create the bitmap
```

This obviously creates compilation issue with the error:

```
error: cannot make type *[]bool
```

I have also tried using the pointer syntax:

```
register[true] = &(make([]bool, len(arr)))
```

Which gives me the error:

```
cannot take the address of make([]bool, len(arr))
```

The reason I want the map values to be `*[]bool` is so that the write back to the map stays sane and in-place.

While go doesn't complain about `map[bool]*[]bool` hence its a valid type.
If it is valid the what is the idomatic way to use it in the fashion I want to. If not then what would be the alternate way?

Comment: `*[]bool` is a pointer, not a slice, therefor you cannot use `make`. I don't know what you mean by "the map stays sane", re-assigning the slice value in the map vs re-assigning the slice value through the pointer should make little difference.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you want a pointer to a slice in the first place; can you clarify? Slices are reference types already, and it's very odd to want to have a pointer to one - what is the precise use case?

Comment: Unless you're doing something highly concurrent and serializing access to the map, then pointer to slice probably provides no benefit over slice.

Comment: this sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you trying to represent? As others have noted a pointer to slice seems redundant - as an empty slice can be represented by a nil value - unless you want to represent an uninitialized state. Again if we had a clear picture of your data-model, we can better help.

Comment: if I directly use a slice instead of pointer to slice, then operation like append won't reflect in the map, unless I reassign the slice back to the map

Comment: That's correct, but why don't you want to reassign to the map? Note that slices headers are fairly small, and hence `m[key] = append(m[key], ...)` is just fine

Comment: @IshanKhare No. I think there's some misunderstanding on how append works. See, https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15. Even if you use a pointer to the slice, it might happen that capacity is not enough to hold the data and then append might allocate a bigger array to store it and the returned slice will point to the new backing array.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to create a pointer to a slice:

```
register := make(Register)
s := make([]bool, len(arr)) // create addressable slice value s.
register[true] = &s
```

You can use `new` to eliminate the variable declaration, but this approach does not reduce the number of lines of code and it adds another map index operation.

```
register := make(Register)
register[true] = new([]bool)
*register[true] = make([]bool, len(arr))
```

Declare a function to move the assignment on to a single line:

```
func makeSlice(n int) *[]bool {
    s := make([]bool, len(arr))
    return &s
}

...

register := Register{true: makeSlice(len(arr))}
```

Because the map keys have two possible values, true and false, you might be able to simplify the code by using a struct instead of a map:

```
type Register struct {
    t, f []bool
}

register := Register{t: make([]bool, len(arr))}
```

The struct fields in `register` are addressable, so you can use `&register.t` to get the `*[]bool`.

A variation on this theme is to use an array:

```
type Register [2][]bool
register := Register{1: make([]bool, len(arr))}
```

If you modify the slice elements only and not the slice value, then there's no need to use a pointer to the slice.

```
type Register map[bool][]bool
register := make(Register)
register[true] := make([]bool, len(arr))
```

If you do modify the slice value, the `map[bool][]bool` may be more efficient and easier to use.  The application will need to assign back to the map when the slice value is modified, but you eliminate the indirections.

Comment: I can do this of course, but is there any workaround if I don't want to use an auxilary variable like s?

Comment: Can you elaborate more by what do you mean with slice 'header' and 'elements' ?

Comment: I see what you mean now @Penelope
but if I do an operation like append, then I'm bound to reassign the new slice back to the map. This won't be the case with a pointer to slice.

Comment: @IshanKhare: if you `append` then you must write that slice value _somewhere_, a pointer does not magically make that disappear, it's just an unessecary indirection in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the `new` function:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   type Register map[bool]*[]bool
   register := make(Register)
   register[true] = new([]bool)
   // main.Register{true:(*[]bool)(0xc000004078)}
   fmt.Printf("%#v\n", register)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/builtin#new